# Altair: showing the value of the current point in the tooltip

Tags: python, pandas, altair, graph-visualization

In the code below, we have a dataset that can be read as: "two cooks `cook1`, `cook2` are doing a competition. They have to make four dishes, each time with two given ingredients `ingredient1`, `ingredient2`. A jury has scored the dishes and the grades are stored in `_score`.

I want to use Altair to show a graph where the x-axis is each dish (1, 2, 3, 4) and the y-axis contains the scores of the two cooks separately. This currently works but the main issue is that on hover, the tooltip does not include the score of the current point that is being hovered.

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ingredient1": ["potato", "onion", "carrot", "beet"],
    "ingredient2": ["tomato", "pepper", "zucchini", "lettuce"],
    "dish": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "cook1": ["cook1 dish1", "cook1 dish2", "cook1 dish3", "cook1 dish4"],
    "cook1_score": [0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9],
    "cook2": ["cook2 dish1", "cook2 dish2", "cook2 dish3", "cook2 dish4"],
    "cook2_score": [0.6, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6],
})


value_vars = [c for c in df.columns if c.endswith("_score")]
cook_names = [c.replace("_score", "") for c in value_vars]
id_vars = ["dish", "ingredient1", "ingredient2",] + cook_names
df_melt = df.melt(id_vars=id_vars, value_vars=value_vars,
                  var_name="cook", value_name="score")

chart = alt.Chart(df_melt).mark_circle().encode(
    x=alt.X("dish:O", title="Dish number"),
    y=alt.Y("score:Q", title="Score"),
    color="cook:N",
    tooltip=id_vars
)

chart.show()
```

I tried explicitly adding the score columns to the tooltip:

```
    tooltip=id_vars+value_vars
```

But that yields the following error:

> ValueError: cook1_score encoding field is specified without a type; the type cannot be inferred because it does not match any column in the data.

So how can I get altair to also show the score of (only) the currently hovered element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cook1_score` is not a column in `df_melt`, which is why you see the error. Setting `tooltip=id_vars+['score']` will work.

Comment: Silly oversight. It was clearly time for me to call it a day then. Thanks!