# Altair: only show related field on hover, not all of them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visualization, altair

This is a follow-up question to [a previous (solved) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76384509/altair-showing-the-value-of-the-current-point-in-the-tooltip) about Altair with the same toy dataset.

In the code below, we have a dataset that can be read as: "two cooks cook1, cook2 are doing a competition. They have to make four dishes, each time with two given ingredients ingredient1, ingredient2. A jury has scored the dishes and the grades are stored in _score.

My code is working well already:

- on the y-axis the score is given, both for cook1 and cook2
- in the legend, cook1 and cook2 are separate
- a vertical line is drawn over the nearest x-axis item when hovering

I would like to make changes to the **legend**.

Now it shows the following properties:

- dish (x-axis number)
- ingredient 1, ingredient 2
- `cook1`'s dish, `cook2`'s dish
- score of the cook that we're hovering closest to
- cookX_score (cook1_score, cook2_score) of the cook that we're hovering closest to

Instead, I would like to change it so that the dishes (`cook1` and `cook2`) are not *both* shown but that, just like with `score`, only the respective dish is included. So if I hover closer to a point of `cook1_score` I only want to show `cook1` and not also `cook2`.

My attempts to restrict this have failed, but the reason is simply because Altair does not know that `cook1` and `cook1_score`, and `cook2` and `cook2_score` are linked. But I am not sure how I can tell Altair that so that it only shows the relevant fields when hovering close to a point.

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

alt.renderers.enable("altair_viewer")
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ingredient1": ["potato", "onion", "carrot", "beet"],
    "ingredient2": ["tomato", "pepper", "zucchini", "lettuce"],
    "dish": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "cook1": ["cook1 dish1", "cook1 dish2", "cook1 dish3", "cook1 dish4"],
    "cook1_score": [0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9],
    "cook2": ["cook2 dish1", "cook2 dish2", "cook2 dish3", "cook2 dish4"],
    "cook2_score": [0.6, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6],
})


value_vars = [c for c in df.columns if c.endswith("_score")]
cook_names = [c.replace("_score", "") for c in value_vars]
id_vars = ["dish", "ingredient1", "ingredient2"] + cook_names
df_melt = df.melt(id_vars=id_vars, value_vars=value_vars, var_name="cook", value_name="score")

nearest_dish = alt.selection(type="single", nearest=True, on="mouseover", fields=["dish"], empty="none")

# Main chart with marked circles
chart = alt.Chart(df_melt).mark_circle().encode(
    x="dish:O",
    y="score:Q",
    color="cook:N",
    tooltip=id_vars + ["score", "cook"]
).add_selection(
    nearest_dish
)

# Draw a vertical rule at the location of the selection
vertical_line = alt.Chart(df_melt).mark_rule(color="gray").encode(
    x="dish:O",
).transform_filter(
    nearest_dish
)

# Combine the chart and vertical_line
layer = alt.layer(
    chart, vertical_line
).properties(
    width=600, height=300
).interactive()

layer.show()
```

Note: I'm stuck on `Altair<5`.

Comment: I think you would have to melt the df differently for that to happen, e.g. so that you have a column called `dish_number` and another called `dish` that contains the name of the dish in long format.

Comment: @joelostblom Thanks for the tip. I figured it out indeed by adding a separate column for the dish itself. So I posted that as an answer.

Comment: Great, thanks for posting back the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up modifying my DataFrame so that every row contains the dish name and the scores separately as well. That way I could target those items within the tooltip.

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

alt.renderers.enable("altair_viewer")
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ingredient1": ["potato", "onion", "carrot", "beet"],
    "ingredient2": ["tomato", "pepper", "zucchini", "lettuce"],
    "dish_id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "cook1": ["cook1 dish1", "cook1 dish2", "cook1 dish3", "cook1 dish4"],
    "cook1_score": [0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9],
    "cook2": ["cook2 dish1", "cook2 dish2", "cook2 dish3", "cook2 dish4"],
    "cook2_score": [0.6, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6],
})


value_vars = [c for c in df.columns if c.endswith("_score")]
cook_names = [c.replace("_score", "") for c in value_vars]
id_vars = ["dish_id", "ingredient1", "ingredient2"] + cook_names
df_melt_score = df.melt(id_vars=["dish_id", "ingredient1", "ingredient2"], value_vars=value_vars, var_name="cook_score", value_name="score")
df_melt_score["cook"] = df_melt_score["cook_score"].str.replace("_score", "")
df_melt_score = df_melt_score.drop(columns=["cook_score"])
df_melt_dish = df.melt(id_vars=["dish_id", "ingredient1", "ingredient2"], value_vars=["cook1", "cook2"], var_name="cook", value_name="dish_name")

df_concat = pd.merge(df_melt_score, df_melt_dish, on=["dish_id", "cook", "ingredient1", "ingredient2"], how="left").reset_index()

nearest_dish = alt.selection(type="single", nearest=True, on="mouseover", fields=["dish_id"], empty="none")

# Main chart with marked circles
chart = alt.Chart(df_concat).mark_circle().encode(
    x="dish_id:O",
    y="score:Q",
    color="cook:N",
    tooltip=["dish_id", "ingredient1", "ingredient2", "cook", "dish_name"]
).add_selection(
    nearest_dish
)

# Draw a vertical rule at the location of the selection
vertical_line = alt.Chart(df_melt_score).mark_rule(color="gray").encode(
    x="dish_id:O",
).transform_filter(
    nearest_dish
)

# Combine the chart and vertical_line
layer = alt.layer(
    chart, vertical_line
).properties(
    width=600, height=300
).interactive()

layer.show()
```